# Disable TFS checkout nag

Tags: c#, tfs, visual-studio-2012

Is there any way I can get TFS to just perform a checkout from the solution explorer menu without asking me a bunch of stupid questions?  I just want to hit 'checkout for edit' and have it check out the file with all the defaults set.  Instead a get a really annoying dialog with a bunch of options I don't care about.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tools >> Options >> Source Control >> Environment

There is an option "Display silent check out command in menus"

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Under Tools/Options select Source Control.

Under the Environment option, there is a "Checked-in Item" group.

You should be able to select "Check out automatically" for Editing and Saving.

This should automatically check out a file.